# JavaScript Jasmine unit test coverage

Tags: javascript, jasmine

Folks,
  Lets say I have the following function.  What would be a proper way to write a Spy, or any other method of testing this with Jasmine?

```
var Ideas = require('../models/Ideas').Ideas;

var doSomething = function doSomething(req, rsp, userId) {
    controllerHelper.batchGet(req, rsp,
        function(ids) { return Ideas.get(ids, userId); },
        function(tags) { return Ideas.getTags(tags, userId); },
        function(tags) { return Ideas.getSpecificTags(tags, userId); },
        function() { return Ideas.getAll(userId); });
};
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to test if the function has been called or with what arguments it was called you can use `jasmine.createSpy()`...

```
it("should test your function", function () {        
    doSomething = jasmine.createSpy();
    doSomething(1,2,3);
    expect(doSomething).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(doSomething).toHaveBeenCalledWith(1,2,3);
});
```

If you want to test the return result of the function you can just call it in your expect...

```
it("should test your function", function () {                
    expect(doSomething(req, rsp, userId)).toEqual(expectedResult);
});
```